# postfix issue with combined check of sender-domain, login and IP Whitelisting

Tags: postfix

I would like to have a postfix that allows mail relay to a relayhost when

a) the sender-domain is allowed

and one of:

b) the sender has authenticated
c) the client has a IP whitelist entry

my current approach so far is:

```
relayhost = [RELAYHOST]:25
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
  check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/ip_whitelist, 
  permit_sasl_authenticated, 
  reject_unauth_destination
```

with restricted_senders containing

```
example.com   OK
```

and ip_whitelist containing

```
192.168.1.3   OK
```

While sending mails from either authenticated clients or IP whitelisted clients works, the sender domain restriction does not work. It seems as soon as authentication or client_access match, the sender restriction doesn't get checked anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Why this does not work?

The [`smtpd_sender_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions):

> The default is to permit everything.
>
> Specify a list of restrictions, separated by commas and/or whitespace. Continue long lines by starting the next line with whitespace. Restrictions are applied in the order as specified; the first restriction that matches wins.

and

> `check_sender_access type:table`
>
> Search the specified [access(5)](https://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) database for the `MAIL FROM` address, domain, parent domains, or `localpart@`, and execute the corresponding action.

Therefore, your configuration first permits `example.com` from `/etc/postfix/restricted_senders` and then permits everything else. The [`smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender) does not change that, because:

> An address is considered "unknown" when 1) it does not match a [virtual(5)](https://www.postfix.org/virtual.5.html) alias or [canonical(5)](https://www.postfix.org/canonical.5.html) mapping, and 2) the address is not valid for its address class. For a definition of class-based address validation, see [ADDRESS_CLASS_README](https://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_CLASS_README.html#classes).

The domain, e.g., `example.org` is not in *local*, *virtual alias*, *virtual mailbox* nor *relay* domain class, so it falls into the ***default domain class***. This class has no destination nor valid recipient tables. Apparently any address that does not belong to the other domain classes is valid for this address class. This is logical, as the local system would not know which addresses are available on the remote system.

## `smtpd_sender_restrictions` are sufficient for this

Forget about the [`smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender) as this could be done using `smtpd_sender_restrictions` alone.

- The easiest configuration would be:

  ```
  smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
      check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders,
      reject
  ```
- An alternative could be using `regex:` tables:

  ```
  smtpd_sender_restrictions = 
      check_sender_access regex:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders
  ```

  This enables using *regular expressions*:

  ```
  /example\.com$/  OK
  //               550 You are not allowed to use this sender address.
  ```

  You can test the lookup results with [`postmap -q`](https://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html):

  ```
  $ /usr/sbin/postmap -q user@example.org regexp:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders
  550 You are not allowed to use this sender address.

  $ /usr/sbin/postmap -q user@example.com regexp:/etc/postfix/restricted_senders
  OK
  ```

Comment: that was it, thank you very much. I'm not allowed to upvote yet, but marked it as solved